# Xcode 14.1 Simulator and "exclude architecture arm64" results in SwiftPackageManager linker error on iOS >=14

Tags: linker-errors, arm64, swift-package-manager, apple-silicon

Apple suggests excluding architecture arm64 für Simulator builds for Xcode 14.3 to avoid problems with legacy libraries which are not available as xcframeworks on Apple Silicon Macs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon#Update-pre-compiled-libraries-from-vendors

When I try to exclude arm64 architecture for simulators in an project that also uses a SwiftPackageManager Dependency (e.g. Kingfisher), I get a linker error when building for iOS 14 or higher, but building for iOS13 works fine.

Code:

```
_ = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string:"https://picsum.photos/200/300")!)
```

Linker Error-Log:

```
Undefined symbol: _$s10Kingfisher13ImageResourceV11downloadURL8cacheKeyAC10Foundation0E0V_SSSgtcfC
Undefined symbol: _$s10Kingfisher13ImageResourceVMa
```

[XCode Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Incmb.png)

[ViewController Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYjM.png)

Do you have any suggestions how to avoid this linker error? Why does it only happen on iOS14+?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with xCode 14.3 on macOS 13.3.1.

The solution for me was this - Go to the "Product" menu in the menu bar and select Destination > Destination Architectures > Show Rosetta Destinations.
Then you will see Rosetta in parenthesis next to the simulator name. Run it. That's all.

Hope this helps.
Here is the original source of this information - [Link](https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/)